# Which driver should I use for this Atheros network adapter?

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

I ran the command `sudo lshw -c network` and here is the hardware info. for my network adapter. I have build all the modules related to Atheros, and have load them already. But none of them could help me active my network adapter.

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: AR8162 Fast Ethernet
   vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: 10
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f1800000-f183ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched the Internet for a long time, and it turns out we do not have a driver for this device :(